# Sampling from all possible floats in D

Tags: random, floating-point, d

In the D programming language, the standard random (std.random) module provides a simple mechanism for generating a random number in some specified range.

```
auto a = uniform(0, 1024, gen);
```

**What is the best way in D to sample from *all possible* floating point values?**

For clarification, sampling from all possible 32-bit integers can be done as follows:

```
auto l = uniform!int(); // randomly selected int from all possible integers
```

Comment: Well, I don't know the best way, but I'd probably start with a random int, then filter out nonsense (well, unless you want them, like float can be negative zero, or some not-a-number with a random payload, technically that is a possible floating point value), and reinterpret cast it back to float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the kind of distribution you want.

A uniform distribution over all possible values could be done by generating a random ulong and then casting the bits into floating point. For `T` being float or double:

```
union both { ulong input; T output; }
both val;
val.input = uniform!"[]"(ulong.min, ulong.max);
return val.output;
```

Since roughly half of the positive floating point numbers are between 0 and 1, this method will often give you numbers near zero.`It will also give you infinity and NaN values.

Aside: This code should be fine with D, but would be undefined behavior in C/C++. Use `memcpy` there.

If you prefer a uniform distribution over all possible *numbers* in floating point (equal probability for 0..1 and 1..2 etc), you need something like the normal `uniform!double`, which unfortunately does not work very well for large numbers. It also will not generate infinity or NaN. You could generate `double` numbers and convert them to `float`, but I have no answer for generating random large `double` numbers.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind briefly explaining the use of `both` in the first and second lines?